# Error while setting object or calling function EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=257)

Tags: ios, swift

I had created some custom UIViews and implemented in another UIView in my projects.
I'm getting a crash while calling some functions or setting values to some objects but not getting crash when setting property.
Refer below code to understand code and question properly.

```
class SearchProfileDetailView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var userInfoTable: UITableView!

    var userObject: UserObject?

    override init(frame:CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        loadViewFromNib()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        loadViewFromNib()
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "SearchProfileDetailView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        view.frame = bounds
        self.addSubview(view);

    }

    func setColor() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
}
```

I've used this **SearchProfileDetailView** in another UIView with the interface builder and assigned outlet refer below code.

```
class SearchResultView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var profileDetailView: SearchProfileDetailView!

    var currentIndex: Int?

    override init(frame:CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        loadViewFromNib()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        loadViewFromNib()
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "SearchResultView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        view.frame = bounds
        self.addSubview(view);
    }
    func setUserProfile(userObject: UserObject) {
        profileDetailView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red  // Not Crashed      
        profileDetailView.userObject = userObject //Crashed with error mentioned in title of question
        profileDetailView.setColor() ////Crashed with error mentioned in title of question
    }
}
```

> Crashed while calling profileDetailView.setColor() and
>   profileDetailView.userObject = userObject But not crashed on
>   profileDetailView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

Now I've used this **SearchResultView** into UIViewController with the interface builder.

```
class ExploreViewController: UIViewController {

      @IBOutlet weak var searchResultView: SearchResultView!

      func getResult() {
           SearchAPIHandler().search(params: parameters) {[weak self] (responseData) in
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  guard let strongSelf = self else {
                            return
                   }
                   if let users = responseData.users, !users.isEmpty {
                          strongSelf.searchResultView.setUserProfile(userObject: users[0])
                   }
              }

      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried so much and now I've got to know that problem was with my interface builder.

There was none module.

I checked Inherit Module From Target and everything works well.

[image]